# Running Jar file with external properties

Tags: java, jar, java-8, jvm

I have jar file that I want to run along with specific properties file. I am running following command to execute that jar

```
java –jar –DApp.config.file=local.properties App.jar
```

With this command I am getting following error

```
Could not load properties from class path resource [local.properties]: class path resource [local.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Based on what I read so far if you are passing -jar then you don't have to worry about $CLASSPATH. Am I missing something here ?

PS - local.properties and jar files are in same directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-jar` option specifies the jar file to launch, hence, has to remain right before the naming of the intended jar file:

```
java –DApp.config.file=local.properties –jar App.jar
```

Don’t place other options between `–jar` and `App.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following snipped to access external properties file and run your jar file:

```
java -jar jarname.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/propertyfile.properties
```